# (MATLAB) How to obtain the max and min background of a series of images?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, max, min

I'm having troubles on how to obtain the max and min of the background of a series of images. I made this function which calculates the mean by adding all the pixel values and then divide by a total number of pixels:

```
function [Ifondo] = promedioImgs(pathImages)
fn = sprintf('%s*.jpeg',pathImages);
indexImages = dir(fn);
numImages=length(indexImages);

Ifondo=0;
for i=1:numImages
    fn = sprintf('%s%s',pathImages,indexImages(i).name);
    primera=imread(fn);
    primera=double(primera);
    if(i==1)
        Ifondo=double(primera);
    else
        Ifondo=Ifondo+primera;
    end
end

Ifondo=uint8(round(Ifondo/numImages));
end
```

In this function Ifondo is the background image I want to obtain(the folder contains 100 images) . Getting the mean works fine, but I can't get around on how to do it for max and min. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with max and min in this case?

Comment: How much RAM do you have available for image processing? Are you limited in RAM usage and this the reason why you choose an additive approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get the min and max backgrounds. Here what I have done is, taking the r,g,b values of each image separately, then get the min and max of them and later combining them to make the max and min backgrounds.

Hope this will help :)

Have a nice day.

Thanks

```
function [mean_Ifondo,max_Ifondo,min_Ifondo] = promedioImgs(pathImages)

fn = sprintf('%s*.jpg',pathImages);
indexImages = dir(fn);
numImages=length(indexImages);
fn = sprintf('%s%s',pathImages,indexImages(1).name);
primera=imread(fn);


sz = size(primera);
ar = zeros(numImages,sz(1),sz(2),sz(3));
r = zeros(numImages,sz(1),sz(2));
g = zeros(numImages,sz(1),sz(2));
b = zeros(numImages,sz(1),sz(2));


Ifondo=0;
for i=1:numImages
    fn = sprintf('%s%s',pathImages,indexImages(i).name);
    primera=imread(fn);
    primera=double(primera);

    ar(i,:,:,:) = primera;

    r(i,:,:) = ar(i,:,:,1);
    g(i,:,:) = ar(i,:,:,2);
    b(i,:,:) = ar(i,:,:,3);

    if(i==1)
        Ifondo=double(primera);
    else
        Ifondo=Ifondo+primera;
    end
end

mean_Ifondo= uint8(round(Ifondo/numImages));

for i = 1:sz(1)
    for j = 1:sz(2)
      max_r(i,j) = max(r(:,i,j));
      max_g(i,j) = max(g(:,i,j));
      max_b(i,j) = max(b(:,i,j));

      min_r(i,j) = min(r(:,i,j));
      min_g(i,j) = min(g(:,i,j));
      min_b(i,j) = min(b(:,i,j));     

    end
end

max_Ifondo(:,:,1) = max_r;
max_Ifondo(:,:,2) = max_g;
max_Ifondo(:,:,3) = max_b;
min_Ifondo(:,:,1) = min_r;
min_Ifondo(:,:,2) = min_g;
min_Ifondo(:,:,3) = min_b;

end
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick attempt to answer your question for image processing. A thing to note about what you are looking for. A maximum in an image stack is supposed to be the largest values in the entire stack. Minimum are the smallest values in the stack. So by doing comparisons looking for either the smallest or largest as you load the pictures should generate the picture you are looking for by the end.

```
for i=1:numImages
    fn = sprintf('%s%s',pathImages,indexImages(i).name);
    primera=imread(fn);
    primera=double(primera);
    if(i==1)
        Ifondo=double(primera);
    else
        IDX = Ifondo < primera; % Finding larger values from next loaded img
        Ifondo(IDX) = primera(IDX); % pixels found larger in primera, overlap those same pixels in Ifondo
    end
end
```

This is how I would do it using your code.